# Add screenshots for passing cypress tests in mochawesome report

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

I want to add screenshots for passing tests in the mochawesome html report.

I have managed to add screenshots for a failing test in the html report via the following and was wondering if this could be updated to support screenshots for passing tests?

index.js

```
import addContext from 'mochawesome/addContext'

Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
    if (test.state === 'failed') {
      addContext({test}, { title: "Screenshot", value:`${Cypress.config('screenshotsFolder')}/${Cypress.spec.name}/${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed).png` })
    }
  })
```

Comment: This explains in detail on how to add screenshots to mocha reports - https://medium.com/egnyte-engineering/3-steps-to-awesome-test-reports-with-cypress-f4fe915bc246

Comment: thanks but does not answer how I can add screenshots for passing tests @AlapanDas

Comment: If you remove your if statement, would it not add the screenshot regardless of the outcome?

Comment: I think you just add cy.screenshot() at the end of the test with the cofiguration you use for the failed screenshots should work, since it will wait for all the other commands to be successfull before execuriting. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot.html#Syntax

Comment: @AlapanDas your article only explain for making sreenshots of tests that pass to mochawesome, even if calling cy.screenshot with correct filename on test that pass, fail to take the screenshot.